# KeyError at Index 0 when applying function to dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a basic code - my aim is to use gender_guesser.detector to find the gender for rows in a dataframe where the imported file (from CSV) would be missing those values. For simplicity, I just created a dummy dataframe in the code below.

I am pretty new to Python and very much in the learning phase so I assume that there are definitely more elegant solutions to what I am trying to do. My idea was to add a new column, find the values for each row using the above mentioned function and then fill out the NaN values while keeping the original gender values where applicable (dropping the temp column once it's done).
The d.get_gender part works if I manually apply it to a specific row and Jupyter accepts the function as well.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([['Adam','Smith',''],['Lindsay','Jackson','M'],['Laura','Jones','F'],['Arthur','Jackson','']] ,columns=['first_name','last_name','gender'])
import gender_guesser.detector as gender
df['newgender']=""

def findgender(dataframe):
    for row in dataframe:
        d = gender.Detector()
        df.loc[row, 'newgender'] = d.get_gender(df.loc[row,'first_name'])
    return df

df.apply(findgender, axis=1)
```

When I then try to apply this to my dataframe, I get a lengthy error message, the last line being
KeyError: ('Adam', 'occurred at index 0')

I tried to look up similar posts here but for most, adding axis=1 solved the issue - as I already have it, I am clueless why the code is not working.
Any help or explanation on why the issue is occurring would be extremely helpful.

Comment: What is the output when you print your dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are getting that error. Usually, it is better to avoid accessing a dataframe line by line. The following solution seems to work using a lambda function.

```
import pandas as pd
import gender_guesser.detector as gender


df = pd.DataFrame([['Adam','Smith',''],['Lindsay','Jackson','M'],['Laura','Jones','F'],['Arthur','Jackson','']] ,columns=['first_name','last_name','gender'])

df['newgender'] = df['first_name'].apply(lambda x: gender.Detector().get_gender(x))
```

It produces the following result.

```
  first_name last_name gender      newgender
0       Adam     Smith                  male
1    Lindsay   Jackson      M  mostly_female
2      Laura     Jones      F         female
3     Arthur   Jackson                  male
```